# What is "^" operation in Java Program?

Tags: java

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        num += digits[i]*(10^(n-1-i));
        System.out.println(10^(n-1-i));
    }
```

My purpose is to change a array representation of a number into Integer representation. For example, [9,9] is 9*(10^1) + 9*(10^0) = 90+9 = 99. 
However, the output of `10^(n-1-i)` is:

```
11
10
```

Is anything wrong with my code, or there is the other way to operate "^"? 
Thank you.

Comment: `^` is not raising into power, `Math.pow`

Comment: @Aominè despite the title, that question is actually asking about a logical xor, not bitwise. But I'm sure there's a question out there for bitwise...

Comment: You're looking for Math.pow as in Math.pow(10, (n-1-i)). ^ is bitwise XOR, don't worry about it for now.

Comment: Please do some **research**. It's as simple as a **web search** for [`java operators`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+operators), which will lead you to pages like "[The Java™ Tutorials - Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)", that clearly show `^` as being **bitwise exclusive OR**.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `^` is a XOR operation, as specified by [the Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).
Java does not provide an operator that implements raising to a power. Either use [Math.pow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) or code your own function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is xor, not raising into power, which is `Math.pow`; you can try to get rid of power at all:

```
int power = 1;

for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    num += digits[i] * power;

    power *= 10; 
}
```